# React select filters on search but the search text is not visible

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react select for dropdown select, when i search in the options, the options are getting filtered but the searched text is not visible in the input box ,

This is my react select component

```
<Select value={props.selectedSpare} onChange={props.updateSelectedSpare}
        options={props.components}
        searchable={true}
        onBlurResetsInput={false}
        style={{
          minHeight: '31px',
          lineHeight: '1em',
          padding: '10px',
          width: '70%',
          marginRight: '25px'
        }}
      />
```

selectedspare value is an object with value and lebel properties ex: {value: null, label: null}

this is my onchange function

```
updateSelectedSpare = selectedSpare => {
this.setState({
  selectedSpare: selectedSpare
    ? selectedSpare
    : { value: null, label: null }
});
```

};
Please let me know what i am missing. Thanks

Comment: post your onChange function, i think the problem occurred in your onChange while setting your value. Check this demo made with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/select2-component-demo

Comment: on search the on-change function doesn't get triggered right? so whats happening  is i am searching 'abc' and its filtering the options according to 'abc' but i cant see abc in my search bar

Comment: post the `updateSelectedSpare` code

Comment: i have updated my question with the onchange code

Comment: Could you please check the demo  again

Comment: i tried with a simple string as state variable too, same error

Comment: Also onchange function doesnt get triggered on search